# Lost reputation, but can't figure why

Tags: support, reputation

Yesterday I lost 10 rep. I can't figure why.

```
-3   yesterday
--------------
+5   10:46     upvote   How does formatting works with a PowerShell function that returns a set of elements?
+2   09:41     accept   How does formatting works with a PowerShell function that returns a set of elements?
-10  15:19     removed  User was removed
```

The "User was removed" is not clickable, and in my profile, I can't see anything in my activity related to this reputation lost.

Can you enlighten me ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

"User was removed" indicates that a user voted for one of your posts had their account deleted  - the account deletion is because either it was requested by them, or removed for other reasons(spam account destroyed etc).

As a result, all of their votes were undone, and the rep you gained/lost was reversed.

Since the upvote was removed, you lost the 10 rep

Comment: thx for the clarification.

Comment: I had the same thing (loss of reputation) happen to me today, and managed to find this answer, which explains it well.  Is it possible that the "User was removed" note could be changed to a link which contains this explanation?

Comment: @PJC not a bad idea - consider posting it as a feature request

Comment: @Sathya - I'm relatively new here (note my rep ;) ) - if you can point me in the right direction, I'll happily do that!

Comment: @PJC [here you go](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/ask?title=%22User%20was%20removed%22%20note%20could%20be%20changed%20to%20a%20link%20which%20contains%20this%20explanation?&tags=reputation+feature-request)

Comment: @Sathya Thanks - seems there's already a thread here [link](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/130122/more-descriptive-user-was-removed-explanation "More Descriptive User Was Removed explanation")